# Is it possible to add an email alias under a domain alias in Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

This is our setup:

- Our primary domain is for example `abc.com`.
- We added `def.com` as a domain alias.
- One of our users is `support@abc.com`. It now has a `support@def.com` email alias.
- We would like to add `help@def.com` as an email alias for `support@abc.com`. but in the administration console it is only possible to add an `@abc.com` alias.

We would just like to be able to forward emails to `help@def.com` to `support@abc.com`.

Is what we want to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Simply add "help@abc.com" as an alias for "support@abc.com".  Since you already have the "def.com" domain-alias in place, the new "help@abc.com" alias will be mirrored by a "help@def.com" alias as well.

You can publicize the "help@def.com" address, and emails sent there will arrive at "support@abc.com".

However, your question did not state whether or not you want to keep the "support@abc.com" secret from the general public.  If there will never be a need to send back replies, then the above setup -- as specified -- will be enough.  On the other hand, if you want replies to be sent from "help@def.com" (and not from "support@abc.com") then you will need to also specify this in the ["Send mail as" section of your GMail account settings](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22377?hl=en).